# Node view engines using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, viewengine, vash

Is there a node view engine that works in conjunction with Angular? Coming from a .NET background VASH seemed like it'd make the most sense however I wasn't able to render a basic {{ 1 + 3 }} expression to ensure my Angular import is working. I also tried making just a plain 'HTML' index page but I got an error saying I needed a default engine. Am i supposed to simply write up html and read it as a file then serve the page? Doing it this way, do I lose out on using layouts? Some direction and ideas would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Angular 1.x (which I assume you're using) does not work with server-rendered pages.  The typical pattern (such as in MEAN) is to consume a RESTful API with Angular, decoupling front-end and back-end.

Angular 2.0 will allow server-rendering and [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) is the project to follow for that.